# Change input language in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea, hebrew

My application is in Hebrew.
The computers that are running my app all have English set as the default language and Hebrew as the secondary language.

Every time they need to input stuff to my JTextFields, they have to "alt + shift" to change language,
Some of them don't even look at the monitor and just begin to write, and I get gibberish because they wrote in Hebrew but with English chars :)

Is it possible to set the language when a JTextFields gets the focus  , or maybe in some other way ?

thanks,

**Dave**

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imf/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("iw", "IL"));` on `FocusGained` event

Comment: +1, but with one serious limitation. According to my experience "selectInputMethod()" requires administrative rights at least on Windows 7 and later.

Comment: How can I do the same on a JOptionPane ?

Comment: Jdialog has getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("iw", "IL")) because extends Window class, that method is identical.

Comment: JOptionPane has getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("iw", "IL")) too.