# Change input dialog locale to hebrew in java

Tags: java, swing, locale, joptionpane, hebrew

My application is in Hebrew. The computers that are running my app all have English set as the default language and Hebrew as the secondary language

Every time they need to input stuff to the app, they have to "alt + shift" to change language.

In my last question --> 
[Change input language in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959166/change-input-language-in-java/25959266#25959266)
I got a great idea of how to set the locale for text fields, and it worked perfectly !

Now I need to do the same in all my popup Input dialogues.

The previous solution was based on using the FocusGained method of the JTextField FocusListener,
now I don't have a FocusGained option, at least as far as I know :)

IE:

```
response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(requestLine.this, ("<html><b><font color=\"#8F0000  +
  +   \"size=\"10\" face=\"Ariel\">" + "הכנס סטטוס חדש: " + "</font></p></html>"), "");
```

**This option pane asks for input, and stores it in a string, I need it to pop up ready for input in Hebrew .**

Is that even possible ?

Thanks,
**Dave**

Comment: Absolutely possible, although maybe not through JOptionPane. You might need to do this manually using a modal JDialog

Comment: can you show me an example please ?

Comment: Please post a short working example. `requestLine.this` doesn't tell us anything. If the `JOptionPane` contains a text field you can use its `FocusListener`.

Comment: RequestLine.this is a Jpanel

Comment: And the panel contains what? Where does the user enter text in the `JOptionPane`? Better is to post a short working example. Also, use `@username` to reply to comments.

Comment: @user1803551 - JoptionPane opens an Input dialogue and the user enters input there. it's the common use of a showinputDialogue, code example is not required in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will duplicate `showInputDialog` with the locale change:

```
public class LocaleOptionPane extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new LocaleOptionPane();
    }

    LocaleOptionPane() {

        Locale loc = new Locale("iw", "IL");
        String message = "<html><b><font color=\"#8F0000\" size=\"10\" face=\"Ariel\">" + "הכנס סטטוס חדש: " + "</font></p></html>";

        setVisible(true);

        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        pane.setWantsInput(true);

        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(this, UIManager.getString("OptionPane.inputDialogTitle", loc));
        dialog.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(loc); // pane.getInputContext... also works
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();

        String response = (String) pane.getInputValue();
        if (response == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE)
            System.out.println("aborted");
        else
            System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I didn't add the green question-mark icon because it didn't seem well placed anyway, though it can be added by changing `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE` to `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE`.
- You can change the title through the `pane.createDialog` call.
- Implement your own behavior when checking the value of `response`.
- Change the parent component.

Comment: @DavidGidony Yeah, the automatic focus is a bit more difficult due to technical reasons. It is possible with a completely different approach to get the focus, but it will suffer in other departments. If I get something working I'll post it here.

Comment: @DavidGidony Of course, creating your own dialog and specifying its functionality will do it, but the code is longer and more complicated. `JOptionPane` is meant to be fast and not so customizable.

Comment: cool thanks. the idea of changing the input to Hebrew came from the issue that users didn't look at the screen and started typing, and then realized they have written everything in english instead of Hebrew, now, when they still don't look at the screen, they just start writing, and as soon they are using 'space' , the ok box is clicked, because the focus was on the ok box all along.

Comment: hi, any ideas for me :)

Comment: @DavidGidony I said "creating your own dialog and specifying its functionality will do it".

Comment: I don't really know how to do it, can you post me an example please ?

Comment: one last thing to make it perfect. how can I set the inputfield to use ENTER as OK, is it somekind of jtextfield listener for the enter key ? is it simple to add to the code you posted, again , thanks, you are really helping me.

Comment: @DavidGidony I changed my approach so the code is more compact and gives the behavior you want.

Comment: I just love you man :)  I wish there was more ways to flag you and give you points . thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidGidony Bevakasha.

Answer (score 0):

`public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
  private JTextField text = new JTextField();
  public MyDialog() { //set this up with the text field and an "OK" button
    super(null);
    // ...
  }
  public String getValue() {
    return text.getText();
  }
}`

Then later in your code...

`MyDialog md = new MyDialog();
md.setModal(true);
md.pack();
md.setVisible(true); // will block here until the dialog closes
String val = md.getValue();`