# How to Change language of textbox in javafx on click of a button?

Tags: java, swing, chat, javafx-8

I want to build a chat Application in JavaFx in which there will be a button that lets user switch between languages English and Hindi (Indian regional language).The problem is I am not able to figure out how am I suppose to change the language of text of a JavaFx Textbox when the user clicks the button. I have not yet started developing my project because of this problem. Plz just give me a demo program that changes the text in the textbox when a button is clicked.

Thanks!!!

EDIT:
I Tried doing this, SOrry I have never use resource bundles or locales to change text dynamically so i dont know how to implement it....

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class demoLang extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public demoLang() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("language");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Change");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(71, 71, 71)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(116, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 162, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(123, 123, 123))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Locale local = new Locale("hi","IN");
    Locale.setDefault(local);

    jTextField1.setLocale(local);
    jTextField1.setText("" + local.getDisplayLanguage());
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demoLang.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demoLang.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demoLang.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demoLang.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new demoLang().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. First, are you using JavaFX or Swing? These are two different UI toolkits. You say you are using JavaFX, but your code uses Swing. Second, you cannot possibly do what you say without access to some kind of translation service that can translate arbitrary text in English to text in Hindi, and vice versa. Implementing such a service is a highly non-trivial task that is (far) beyond the scope of a question in this forum. If you have such a service, then you just need to call that API, but no-one can answer this question without knowing that API.

Comment: This also appears to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817646/javafx-swing-textfield-typing-language-change-on-click-of-button

Comment: Either of them will satisfy...
That means you are saying input language cannot be changed without use of a translation service????

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959166/change-input-language-in-java

Even the solution of the above question didn't satisfy my requirements....I just basically need that when user selects a particular language (Hindi /  english) labeled on a button then the input language of the textfield switches to that language.... 
I tried the focus listener but i am not getting the output Plz help with these problem

Comment: What do you mean by "the input language of the text field changes". The user can type arbitrary text into a text field. Are you wanting to automatically change the language of that text? Fairly obviously, that would involve some kind of translation service.

Comment: that means If the user selected hindi then while he is typing in the textfield the display text should be hindi

Comment: any luck with the asnwer???

Comment: Still struggling with the question.

Comment: Ok here i'll try again...

I am implementing a chat app using either javafx / swing, where i am stuck is the part of providing multiple language support to user. In the gui, A button will be available that changes the language to either hindi or english. This is d part where i am not understanding how do i implement it. If the user clicks hindi then the language displayed in the textfield when user types must be hindi. 

feel freee to tell if more explanation is needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok!!! Finally, Found an answer for the problem...

There are 2 major translation services available one is paid and one is free.

Sharing the Solution:

I used [java-google-translate-text-to-speech](http://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/) instead of [Google Translate API v2](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/) Java.

About java-google-translate-text-to-speech

The Api is unofficial with the main features of Google Translate in Java.

It also provide text to speech api. If you want to translate the text "Hello!" in Hindi just write:

```
Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
String text = translate.translate("Hello!", Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
System.out.println(text); // "नमस्ते"
```

It's free!

One Important Point: Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service.
Google Translate API is available as a paid service. See the Pricing and FAQ pages on google for details.

BUT, java-google-translate-text-to-speech is FREE!
There is one issue with the API Since google updated its code. The custom Version can be downloaded from this [direct link](https://java-google-translate-text-to-speech.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=80008000&name=custom-translate-api.jar&token=ABZ6GAe5C64d4hhaN8OP9V-2qqYQ4nOkFw%3A1448107017061&id=8&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAeaVVlQLOKOaBHdZ75yim3Z4WVNZg%3A1448107017061).

Thanks!!! Now you can Close the Thread :)